# Security risk in passing session ID/ keys as request parameters

Tags: java, javascript, security, encryption, cryptography

We are developing a RESTful chat API and a chat client. When the client makes the 'initial connect' request, we return a json response with security key and a user id. For the subsequent requests the client should send user id and security key as request parameters. Please note that Chat is allowed only between logged-in users and some other component intercepts all the requests and does authentication and authorization.

1. Is it a security risk to send security key and user id (by client) with each request
2. If so what is the remedy/ solution

Comment: Against what would you like to secure your system?

Comment: Against an interceptor stealing the key and userId and trying to connect to the chat

Comment: In that case you are going to need TLS (https). If you have that, you don't need anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally considered a better practice to put security credentials in a cookie rather than in the URL for a number of reasons.  One such reason is that URLs may be logged by various parts of the infrastructure (browser history, proxy logs, web server log file, etc...), but cookies are generally not captured and stored in that way.